# Ember model hook with a Promise.All and several findAll()

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data, json-api

I thought I understood how the store.findAll and the Promise.All works. But I have run into some strange behavior.
I have two findAll(), but only one of them is fullfilled after the Promise.All gets into the then()-part.

See this code

```
export default Route.extend({
model() {
    var self = this;
    return Ember.RSVP.Promise.all([
        self.store.findAll('contact'),
        self.store.findAll('message')
    ]).then(function(values) {
        var contacts = values[0];
        var messages = values[1];
        var numberOfContacts = contacts.get('length');  // This is 39 as expected.
        var numberOfMessages = messages.get('length');  // This is 0. Expected is 1. 
        ...
```

There must be something different with messages and contacts, but I cannot figure out what it is. They have very similar models and they have very similar backend API handling. From the network traffic I can see that a message object is returned and if I call (later in the code, after the model hook):

```
store.peekAll('message');
```

I get the message object I expect.

I use ember 3.0.0

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out. It is due to a strange behavior of findAll() in Ember.
FindAll() will return immediately with the elements that was already present in the store. Later, when more objects have been retrieved from the server, the store is updated, but the promise of the findAll()-call is long gone.

To work around this strange behavior, there is an option to the findAll() method.

```
{reload: true}
```

It is used this way:

```
return self.store.findAll('message', { reload: true }).then(messages => {
   var messageLength = messages.get('length');
   ...
```

With this reload-option set, findAll() and promises work as expected.

Comment: I'm sure that will help someone in the future.